# Add android library project to Android project in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, android-support-library

I have Android project (main) that has a dependency on Android-library (library) project. I have that in Eclipse where I added library project, but now I want to use Android Studio where I cant find similar option. Is it possible to do it by Gradle where I build library project and main project take that from local repository or I need Maven to do so and if I can then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import your Eclipse library-project (e.g. Facebook library-project), then in your project's `settings.gradle` refer to Facebook project's module local path in this way:

```
include ':facebook'
project(':facebook').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../facebook/app')
```